# PHP upload greater than 64MB has no POST variables

Tags: php, apache, file-upload

I am having a head scratching issue on my LAMP stack using php 5.6 on a linux box.
It seems as if any file under 64MB uploads properly, but anything ABOVE 64MB does not even though my configuration is set to 150MB.
I am using a trace log that I can tail to monitor actions in the upload script.
What happens is that if I uploaded an 8MB file for example, the upload script does not start until the file is uploaded.
This is the normal action.  If I set upload_max_filesize to 4MB the same thing happens except an error is POSTed in the $_FILES array.
When I upload a file greater than 64M with upload_max_filesize set to 150MB, the script will INSTANTLY execute, but no POST information is sent and no errors are returned.  Meanwhile the browser screen does not display until I am guessing the file is uploaded.  When it is done uploading the upload script displays on the browser even though it executed minutes ago.  But, with no POST variables nothing is accessible.  There is also no temporary file created in the /tmp folder. It simply appears to be uploaded to a void.

This is returned in the header:

```
    Content-Type : multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------313526204030269522582777911024
    Content-Length : 73273125
```

It seems as if something looks at Content-Length and then runs script prematurely with no data.

here is my php.ini

```
    memory_limit = 256M
    post_max_size = 150M
    upload_max_filesize = 150M
    max_execution_time = 300
    max_input_time = 1000`
```

I also have a timeout of 300 seconds in Apache
However, the difference between this and all the other upload posts I have read is that there isn't a timeout issue.  The script is instantly executed with no passed data.

Any ideas?

Comment: You restarted services after making the change? If this is new development it should be on a recent version of PHP. You've also verified you are editing the php.ini your PHP version is running by checking php_info()?

Comment: Yes I have a dedicated server and have verified all the obvious.  I do this all the time.  The key here is that if I set max to 8M, then a 9M file generates errors, but a 64M and larger generates NO error and NO post.

Comment: I should also note that I am running Apache/2.4.52 (cPanel) because this seems like it might not be a php problem.

Comment: OK, dodo forgot to check the apache logs!  POST Content-Length of 73273093 bytes exceeds the limit of 57671680 bytes in Unknown on line 0  So, I need to find out where this limit is set, because does not appear to relate to upload_max_filesize.  If set to 8MB  I only see this error if file is over 57671680 , not if under that but still larger than upload_max_filesize=8M

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like it WAS the wrong ini file.
But the odd thing is that the one I edited seemed to do something as well which threw me off.

Sorry for the nuisance.